# Does iPhone 5 have a low battery warning tone?

Tags: iphone

My friend has an iPhone 5 (Verizon), she hears a low battery alert tone when on a call at 10% and 20%. My iPhone 5 (Sprint) has no such tone, anyway I can't find how to enable it if it does.

So if a Verizon iPhone has a low battery alert tone (trill sounding), why doesn't a Sprint iPhone5 have the low battery tone???

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't have but you can install "Battery Alert" app and it will enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the following iPhone models:

- iPhone
- iPhone 3G
- iPhone 3GS
- iPhone 4
- iPhone 4S

All of this time I was using AT&T. None of the phones were jailbroken. My current model is iPhone 4S on AT&T.

I noticed this recently during a call. I had never noticed it before, and I'm a heavy user. I'm not sure if it was something adding during an update by the carrier (AT&T) or one of the iOS updates.

A person on another forum mentioned noticing it ever since the iPhone 3GS. Based on my research so far, it appears that it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be extremely precise, one might say that the tone you hear isn't necessarily a low battery alert tone, but it is a tone to let you know an urgent notification has arrived. (i.e. any alert would sound identical at that point)

Two events that cause these alerts that are audible when you are on a phone call are the low battery alerts that iOS issues.

Most people would just say the tone is for a low battery warning, though. :-)